# Compactness beyond extendibility

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

By a result of Magidor, $\kappa$ is extendible if and only if the infinitary $n$th-order logic over the language $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ is compact for every $n < \omega$, where by compact, we mean that a collection of sentences $\Sigma$ has a model whenever so does every subcollection of size $<\kappa$.

It follows from the proof of the theorem included in Kanamori's book that if $\kappa$ is extendible, then in fact the $\alpha$th-order logic over $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ is compact for every $\alpha \leq \kappa$. Is there a large-cardinal notion that implies that the $\alpha$th-order logic over $L_{\kappa,\kappa}$ is compact, for larger $\alpha$?

Comment: If you look at http://cantorsattic.info/Vopenka under the section "strong compactness of logics", you may find that Vopenka's principle is likely enough (and probably too much) to prove the assertion that such cardinals exist. However, it may be that these cardinals are not precisely the extendible cardinals.